# What type of DBMS would be ideal for advanced search capabilities?

Tags: elasticsearch, rdbms

I am wanting to add advanced search capabilities to my web application, likely with a search engine server like elasticsearch. How do I store my data? Do I store it using a RDBMS or a noSQL database? Would one pose more challenges with one database system versus another? Do I not use a dbms for a primary data store in this case?

I am thinking about using PHP as a backend.

Edit: overall question I am asking, HOW do I integrate a dbms with elasticsearch?

Be gentle.  I am new to this.

Comment: This is "too broad" although nevertheless also a faq. [ask]

Comment: How about this: HOW do I integrate a dbms with elasticsearch?

Comment: You don't appear to have read the link or other relevant [help] links. PS Even though this is too broad, it is also a faq. (Because of others who didn't research.) Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].